# how to stop audio playing if user leaves the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

I have an audio file that plays when a user clicks on one view. my problem is that if they move to another view the audio continues to play. I would like the audio to stop if the user is no longer on that view.

is this done in the viewDidUnload method?

here's the code that plays the audio after a 15sec delay:

```
-(void)startPlaying {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15 target:self selector:@selector(startPlaying) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


    NSString *audioSoundPath = [[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio_file" ofType:@"caf"];

    CFURLRef audioURL = (CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioSoundPath];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(audioURL, &audioID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioID);
}
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // Stop Sound
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(audioID);
```

}